# Get current Windows user from server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, authentication

I have a web application that relies on returning the currently logged in Windows user to determine whether or not that user should have access. It works great on individual workstations but for some reason, it prompts for username and password on our servers instead of just grabbing the login info it needs.

The code behind:

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim auth As Boolean = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
    If auth Then
        Dim arrUserName() As String
        Dim strDomainUserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()
        arrUserName = strDomainUserName.Split("\")
        Return arrUserName(1)
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

In web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

**Why would it work on the individual workstations but not the servers?**

**UPDATE**

I found out it works on an old Windows Server 2008 box but not on any of the 2012 machines.

Comment: so people are logging into the server then going to the ASP.net site?

Comment: @codeMonger123 - Yes

Comment: For the benefit of Wai Fung Au Yeung which has posted this comment as an answer; Which applicationpool identity are you using?

Comment: @Bugs - It's our DefaultAppPool. The identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity.